# I want to know whether the data I have is showing seasonality or not

Tags: time-series, arima, seasonality

I am analyzing weekly data on call money market returns over the period of 12 years on R.
I made a time series plot of the data and wanted to know whether this data shows seasonality or not.
I tried removing seasonality assuming it exists by decomposing and subtracting the seasonal part and also with the seasadj command in R. But the model suggested by auto.arima() includes a seasonal component as well and I'm confused as to how this can happen if I've already adjusted for seasonality.

[image]

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

A quick way to check, since you are using R, is to use function `stl`. Not a silver bullet, but will give you some insight. Alternatively you could fit a very simple structural model using `StructTS` and check if the sesonal part is discernible.

Comment: Thanks a lot, will try it out and get back to you.